# flutter android fingerprint integration

Tags: android, fingerprint, flutter

I am looking for some guidance when using flutter over a platform channel to integrate with android fingerprint authentication.  I have the android part working and the flutter app with call the method, but I can not seem to get just a pop-up of fingerprint authentication like I do in swift, which works fine in the same flutter app, in order for it to pass results to the flutter app and let the flutter app continue on. If anyone has any examples or some guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [local_auth](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/local_auth/README.md) plugin -- it comes with usage instructions and an example app.

Comment: Thanks for that, I totally missed it when I looked through those the first time.

Comment: is it possible to save the fingerprint data in database to authenticate multiple devices with same fingerprint ?

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout git repository with full explanation with source code example.

[Git Repository:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C370c.jpg) https://github.com/myvsparth/flutter_fingerprint_auth

[image]